# Add JavaScript object to an existing JavaScript object in for loop

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I am trying to append a JavaScript object to an existing JavaScript object in the loop.

```js
var object1 = { key1: true, header: 'Title A', Size: 100 };
$.each(elements, function (i, item) {
  let headerDisplay = '';
  headerDisplay = this.title;
  var row = { key1: true, header: '' + headerDisplay + '', Size: 100 };
  Object.assign(object1, row);
});
```

I have tried with `Object.assign()`, but it is giving only the last object.
Expecting output array similar to

```js
var finalObject = [
  { key1: true, header: 'Title A', Size: 100 },
  { key1: true, header: 'Title1', Size: 100 },
  { key1: true, header: 'Title2', Size: 100 },
  ...
];
```

Please let me know how can we add objects to an existing one in loop

Comment: The syntax of your expected output is invalid...

Answer (score 1):

since you are already using jQuery why not try the [`$.extend()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) functionality? it should look something like this:

```js
 var object1 = { "key1": true, "header": "Title A", "Size": 100};
$.each(elements, function (i, item) {
    let headerDisplay = '';
    headerDisplay =  this.title;
    var row = { "key1": true, "header": ""+headerDisplay+"", "Size": 100};
    $.extend(object1, row)
  });
```

keep in mind that this method will modify the first object1.
If that is not the intended behavior you could pass an empty object as the first argument of the function and pass the result to another variable like this:

```js
const newObject = $.extend({}, object1, row)
```

Not sure what you are trying to do but perhaps there are better alternatives to that. Trying to keep a collection of your objects in an array may be another feasible solution. Good luck!!

Comment: Even this and Object.assign looks like same

Answer (score 0):

please try it...:

```js
 var object1 = { "key1": true, "header": "Title A", "Size": 100};
 var res = [object1];
$.each(elements, function (i, item) {
    let headerDisplay = '';
    headerDisplay =  this.title;
    var row = { "key1": true, "header": ""+headerDisplay+"", "Size": 100};
    res.push(row);
  });
```

now you have `res` as `finalObj`.

Comment: ,- I want all the JavaScript objects as one row in array with comma separated. With the code suggested it will add multiple rows. Please let me know how can we add objects as comma separated

Comment: if you wants do it without array you must set a keyName for each object that you wants to add finalObj same as follow:{
 "a": {
  "aa": "1"
 },
 "b": {
  "bb": "1"
 }
}

Comment: you can validate your syntax of JSON object in [https://jsonlint.com/]